# Achoring with Drill versus Anchoring with Spanner

Tags: screws, bench

I'm trying to anchor a bench onto stone. Through holes I've drilled into my bench posts, and holes that I will have drilled into concrete, I plan to drive lag screws.

[image][image]

A fail-proof procedure calls for me to drill the lag screws. Unfortunately, I can't find the socket that would connect my drill and lag screw.

As an alternative to using a socket and drill, I plan to drive the lags using a spanner. A spanner would join the bench and stone less securely, but I'm concerned that the attachment won't be stable enough. Is my concern well founded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, just a general note - driving lag screws like the one pictured above into concrete or stone would need an anchor drilled and set into the concrete, and you'd also want a washer. If you don't have anchors underneath, you'd probably want a concrete anchor screw or another type of fastener.

That said, you'll likely be able to apply more torque with a spanner than you will with a drill. The drill will make driving it go faster and easier, but if you're concerned with hold, I'd finish with the spanner regardless. Sounds like all you really need is a square-drive socket adapter:

[image]

Comment: Concur, no lag into concrete, block, brick, stone without a lag-shield anchor. Also concur that hand driving will be better than using a drill for this application.